# Flutter calling focus on input after the second try returns error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an input that is shown only when I click in a button. Whenever I press the button I request the focus on the input. I can then hide the input again.

The problem is that If I press again the button to show the input, it throws an error:

> FlutterError (setState() called after dispose():
> _ComponentInputState#0f53a(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted) This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget
> that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget
> no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when
> code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The
> preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the
> animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the
> "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure
> the object is still in the tree. This error might indicate a memory
> leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining
> a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the
> tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this
> object during dispose().)

This error occurs because of `inputFocus.requestFocus()` line.

```
class _SaveScreenState extends State<SaveScreen> {
  bool addingNewList = false;

  TextEditingController inputController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode inputFocus = FocusNode();

  Widget content() {
    return ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
        children: [
          showExistingLists(),
          showCreateNewList(),
          buttons(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget showCreateNewList() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: addingNewList,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: inputController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            focusNode: inputFocus,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buttons() {
    return Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Create new list'),
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                addingNewList = true;               
                inputFocus.requestFocus();
              });
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () async {
              setState(() {
                addingNewList = false;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to check if requesting focus was ok, but the problem persists.

```
if (inputFocus.canRequestFocus) {
    inputFocus.requestFocus();
}
```

I also tried without success to put the line outside the `setState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FocusNode()`s and `Controllers()`s need to be disposed after being used. Please read through the error as they also state the solution.

do add this

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    inputController.dispose();
    inputFocus.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: I'm not leaving the screen. I'm just hiding / showing the input, so I believe no need for dispose.

Comment: Try disposing  the focus node on button click

Comment: I actually tried that before and didn't work. But what I forgot is that I should create the `FocusNode` everytime I click the button.... and now it's working.